# How to hide message on the remaining pages in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have the following including of templade blade in main layout:

```
 @if (Auth()->user()->verified == "0")
                @include('common.verify-error')
            @endif
```

So, how to display `@include('common.verify-error')` on the all URL excluding `/test`, `/out`

Should I do this in controller or simple if condition in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, there's probably a few different approaches to this. Personally, I'd do something along the lines of a middleware class...or inject a class in the view, etc.

However, he's another solution that may suit your needs better.

***EDIT:*** Made a change. I'm assuming you use named routes (and should, in the event you want to change urls, etc. You won't have to deal with changing all these if statements for example).

```
@if (Auth()->user()->verified == "0" && !Route::is('test') && !Route::is('out'))
    @include('common.verify-error')
@endif
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#request-path-and-method) method with mask:

```
@if (auth()->user()->verified == 0 && !request()->is('test/*') && !request()->is('out/*'))
    @include('common.verify-error')
@endif
```